# MVC , JS change value textboxfor not posting

Tags: javascript, post, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this modelView

```
 public class Ue
{   public class uEkranModel
        {
            public List<Grup> Grup = new List<Grup>();

            private List<Secim> _secim;
            public List<Secim> secim
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_secim == null)
                        _secim = new List<Secim>();
                    return _secim;
                }
                set { _secim = value; }
            }
        }



public class Secim
        {
            public Guid uGuid { get; set; }
            public Guid fGuid { get; set; }
        }
```

}

I need to fell the List secims items with JS and post it back to controller.

I have tried to :
1)initialize the list in the controller :
   Controller :

```
gidecek.Data = new Models.Ucak.UcakDeneme.uEkranModel();
                    gidecek.Data.secim.Add(new Models.Ue.Secim { uGuid = new Guid() });
                    gidecek.Data.secim.Add(new Models.Ue.Secim { uGuid = new Guid() });
```

View :

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("deneme", "U", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "secimTamam", style = "display:none" }))
{

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Data.secim[0])
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data.secim[0].uGuid, new {id="gidis" })


}
```

JS :

```
   $("#Data_secim_0__ucusGuid").attr("value", index);
```

This way , when the code is executed the value field of the textboxfor is changed(when the JS fired) but when I check the post data in controller , it is NULL.

also tried :
         $("#Data_secim_0__ucusGuid").val(index);

which doesnt cahnge the value of teh textbox.

What I need is to fill the model values with js and post the form with js as well.(The data user is selecting is different, I am just posting back the GUID of the items within a form.)

Comment: Why you are trying to give new id to that text box? check name attribute of that text box in browser, if it is same as Data_secim_0__ucusGuid then your model will bind at controller method

Comment: Tried it as well, when I do like that this is the out put html :
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The ucusGuid field is required." id="Data_secim_0__ucusGuid" name="Data.secim[0].ucusGuid" type="text" value="727b08e3-3a97-48af-9d45-ea0814ecb8c4">

but then again it is empty on the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 possible issues. Your getter is initializing a new `List<Secim>`. Try initializing it in the constructor

```
public class uEkranModel
{
  public uEkranModel()
  {
    secim = new List<Secim>();
  }
  public List<Secim> secim { get; set;}
  ....
}
```

Also I have seen other posts on SO indicating problems posting back GUID's (and one solution that was accepted was to use a view model with the GUID's converted to strings)